# Jhipster EHCache3.x how could definded the disk persistence where in cachaManager

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, jcache, ehcache-3

I was use the jhipster-generator 6.10.5 to generate a proj, use the ehcache as the cacheProvider.

```
package com.xxx.generated.config;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.ehcache.config.builders.*;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;
import org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Configuration;

import org.hibernate.cache.jcache.ConfigSettings;
import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheManagerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernatePropertiesCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.info.GitProperties;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import io.github.jhipster.config.cache.PrefixedKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.Registration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {
    private GitProperties gitProperties;
    private BuildProperties buildProperties;
    private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration;

    public CacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache = jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();

        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()).disk(100, MemoryUnit.MB))
                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds())))
                .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager) {
        return hibernateProperties -> hibernateProperties.put(ConfigSettings.CACHE_MANAGER, cacheManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return cm -> {
            createCache(cm, com.ehc.generated.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE);
            createCache(cm, com.ehc.generated.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE);
            createCache(cm, com.ehc.generated.domain.User.class.getName());
            createCache(cm, com.ehc.generated.domain.Authority.class.getName());
            createCache(cm, com.ehc.generated.domain.User.class.getName() + ".authorities");
            createCache(cm, com.ehc.generated.domain.Book.class.getName());
            createCache(cm, "byId");
            // jhipster-needle-ehcache-add-entry
        };
    }


    private void createCache(javax.cache.CacheManager cm, String cacheName) {
        javax.cache.Cache<Object, Object> cache = cm.getCache(cacheName);
        if (cache == null) {
            cm.createCache(cacheName, jcacheConfiguration);
        }
    }

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setGitProperties(GitProperties gitProperties) {
        this.gitProperties = gitProperties;
    }

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setBuildProperties(BuildProperties buildProperties) {
        this.buildProperties = buildProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new PrefixedKeyGenerator(this.gitProperties, this.buildProperties);
    }
}
```

I can set the .disk on ResourcePoolsBuilder, but how can I set persistence in cacheManager.
jhipster user the Jcache, I can't find any function can config that.
In Ehcahe document, it will use the CacheManagerBuilder to config the persistence.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<String, User> jcacheConfiguration;
    private JCacheCacheManager jCacheCacheManager;

    public CacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache = jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();

        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration
                .fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
                        CacheConfigurationBuilder
                                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, User.class,
                                        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()).disk(10, MemoryUnit.MB,
                                                true))
                                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder
                                        .timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds())))
                                .build());
        CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        EhcacheCachingProvider ehcacheProvider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) cachingProvider;
        DefaultConfiguration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration(ehcacheProvider.getDefaultClassLoader(),
                new DefaultPersistenceConfiguration(new File("D:/training/EHCache/cache")));
        CacheManager cacheManager = ehcacheProvider.getCacheManager(ehcacheProvider.getDefaultURI(), configuration);

        createCache(cacheManager, com.ehc.generated.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE);
        createCache(cacheManager, com.ehc.generated.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE);
        jCacheCacheManager = new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        return hibernateProperties -> hibernateProperties.put(ConfigSettings.CACHE_MANAGER, cacheManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return jCacheCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManagers() {
        return jCacheCacheManager.getCacheManager();
    }
```